# need help with armature and weight painting

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I recently tried to play around making human, but i couldn't figure out the good weight ratio for hip and thigh. it ends up like this

[image]

my weight paint is like this
[image]

[image]

here's the blend file
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to understand your first picture, but your hip has too much influence on the thigh vertices, so simply select your armature, select your mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select the hip bone and use the brush in *Blend* > *Substract* mode to remove this influence. You'll have to bring some other corrections on some other parts of the mesh.

[image]

Comment: I see but it look's like a dent inside the hip. or is it a problem from my topology?

Comment: maybe add a bone between the hip and the leg to make it bend more smoothly?

Comment: After editing for a bit, adding a new bone between hip and leg did decrease the dent. 
thanks for the advice